set MAX DOP using python
I am trying to set the maximum degree of parallelism (MAX DOP) using Python code, but it seems that the code is either not working or not making any changes to the SQL Server.
q = ('''
 EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
    RECONFIGURE


    EXEC sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism', 0
    RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE


    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
    RECONFIGURE;
               ''')
print(q)
engine.execute(text(q).execution_options(autocommit=True))

Below is the SQL code that works fine when executed directly on SQL Server. Could someone please assist me in resolving this issue?
    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
    RECONFIGURE


    EXEC sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism', 0
    RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE


    EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
    RECONFIGURE;


How are you determining that the query, executed from Python, isn't doing anything? You say it is "not working"; are you getting an error?

I;m not getting any error and max dop is not changing in sql server

How are you checking whether it changed?

Probably you have autocommit off so the transaction is, rollbacked

@Charlieface I'm checking in the SQL server by following steps 1.Connect to your SQL Server instance in SSMS.
2.Right-click on the server and select "Properties."
3.In the "Server Properties" dialog, go to the "Advanced" tab.
4.Look for the "Parallelism" section where you can find the "Maximum Degree of Parallelism" setting.

@siggemannen you can check my code i've set autocommit = True

Why are you using WITH OVERRIDE out of curiosity? And why would you want to set it to zero, given that guidance is to set it to 8 for most many-core processors? And if you would want to set it, why would you do it from Python? If you need it for a single query then just use a query hint OPTION (MAXDOP 0)

Each of the commands you want to run must be separate in the session.
q = ('''
 EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
     ''')
print(q)
engine.execute(text(q).execution_options(autocommit=True))

q = ('''
    RECONFIGURE;
     ''')
print(q)
engine.execute(text(q).execution_options(autocommit=True))

q = ('''
    EXEC sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism', 0;
     ''')
print(q)
engine.execute(text(q).execution_options(autocommit=True))

...

